# Struggling to index into a column vector produced using the eval function

Tags: matlab

I have several tables, each with a massive amount of data (20MB each). Let's call them Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, etc. The structure of these tables are similar, with identical column headers (but a varying number of rows). Let's say Attribute_A, Attribute_B, etc.

I am interested in performing calculations on Attribute_B for each table. These calculations involve looping through Attribute_B.

I start by creating a master list with all of my table names.

```
Table_List = [Table_1, Table_2, ... Table 10];
```

Now I can iterate through this and perform my calculations. Doing single calculations works just fine using eval and a concatentation of my column vector name as a function of the value of Current_Table:

```
for Current_Table = Table_List
    Peak_Value = max(eval(strcat(Current_Table,"Attribute_C")));
```

I run into trouble when I perform calculations that require iterating through the column vectors. For instance, the following fails.

```
for Current_Table = Table_List
    for i = 1:length(eval(strcat(Current_Table,".Attribute_B")
        X = X + eval(strcat(Current_Table,".Attribute_B"))(i);
```

MATLAB gets hung up when I try to marry the evaluated column and the desired index value of i. Is there a way to do this?

I understand if I made a single structure of all of the data this would be much easier (not using the string list but actually combining the data). I want to iterate through each of my tables without re-writing data.

Comment: This is, of course, one of many reasons why you shouldn't be using `eval` in the first place. Refactor your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As excaza pointed out, usage of `eval` in this kind of problem is greatly discouraged. One safer and more elegant approach is to use structures.

Here is an example of a program that should be useful to you that uses structures

```
clear
% Intialize the structure that will hold all the tables
TABLES = struct;

% List of table names
table_names = {'Table_1' 'Table_2' 'Table_3'};

% Number of tables
nTables = length(table_names);

% Fill the tables with some data
% TABLES can also be nested structures with more than one data item in them in
% each substructure
for itb=1:nTables
    % TABLES.(table_names{itb}) = rand(3);
    % Load from files with names Table_N.txt
    TABLES.(table_names{itb}) = load([table_names{itb},'.txt']);
end

% Perform operations on the components
for jtb=1:nTables
   % Using a temporary array
   %     temp = []; 
   %     temp = TABLES.(table_names{jtb});
   %     A(jtb) = max(max(temp));
   %     B(jtb) = temp(2,1);
   % .. and such
   % Or directly     
     A(jtb) = max(max(TABLES.(table_names{jtb})));
     B(jtb) = TABLES.(table_names{jtb})(2,1);
 end
```

You have a list of names and you use them to create either nested structures or anything else - like arrays here - inside of the main structure called `TABLES`. You can populate this data from files, in this case I simply used `rand`. Both collecting the data and any operations on it can be done with loops. In the second loop you have an example how you can manipulate the data directly or indirectly using temporary arrays.

This is a relatively broad topic so feel free to ask questions and I'll add them to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response and your willingness to engage in discussion. Here's my hangup - when you create your structure aren't you replicating the data? I want to avoid re-writing my 200MB+ of data into yet another variable and having my workspace double in size. This is the motivation for my (admittedly) wonky approach.

Comment: Is your data in a file? A series of files? You can load it directly into the structure and as far as my knowledge goes, it shouldn't duplicate it. How is your data loaded and handled?

Comment: I've added a simple load from file option. If your loading is more complicated, you can load into a temporary array first and then into the structure. Since your data is not equal sized remember to (just in case) empty the array each time, like `temp = []` in the second loop. I'd say if your loading directly you will not have any duplicates. If you're loading with a temporary array there will be one duplicate of a single table at a time.